# What does "${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}" do in my terminal prompt?

Tags: bash, debian, bashrc, chroot, prompt

In my terminal prompt definition in my `.bashrc` file, among other things, I have this snippet of code:

```
${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}
```

What does this do, and do I need it?

Answer (score 129, accepted):

The important part to answer this question is this snippet from `/etc/bash.bashrc`:

```
if [ -z "$debian_chroot" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi
```

It means if the variable `$debian_chroot` is empty and the file `/etc/debian_chroot` exists and is readable the variable is set to the content of the file.

Now what is this for? The file `/etc/debian_chroot` is when you have a chrooted debian system inside another debian system (ubuntu is based on debian). So this is for a better overview. To distinguish whether you are in the chroot or not.

When you have a chroot of another system for example in `/srv/nfs4/netboot/` you can set a name for this chroot in `/srv/nfs4/netboot/etc/debian_chroot` (in my case it's a nfs4 pxe netboot drive):

```
user@host:~# echo "netboot" >/srv/nfs4/netboot/etc/debian_chroot
```

And then when you chroot inside:

```
chroot /srv/nfs4/netboot/
```

Your prompt looks like this:

```
(netboot)user@host:~#
```

Answer (score 85):

Generally, `${var:+value}` means:

```
if $var is defined and not null; then use 'value'; else do nothing
```

The `debian_chroot` variable is defined in `/etc/bash.bashrc` file. It takes the content of `/etc/debian_chroot` file if this file exists and is readable. By default this file doesn't exists.

For more details, see:

- [What is $debian_chroot in .bashrc?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/3174/37944)
- [Understand this .bashrc script (curly braces, eval, …)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16411133/2353900)

Now, to understand better what exactly it is happening there, do the following in terminal:

```
radu@Radu:~$ PS1='${var:+($var)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
radu@Radu:~$ var="test"
                  ----
                   |
  ------------------
  |
  V
(test)radu@Radu:~$ var=""
radu@Radu:~$ var="and so on"
(and so on)radu@Radu:~$
```

Answer (score 21):

If the environment variable `$debian_chroot` exists and is not empty `${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}` is replaced by `($debian_chroot)` (that is the value of `$debian_chroot` with parens around it).

`$debian_chroot` is set in `/etc/bash.bashrc` to the contents of `/etc/debian_chroot` if that file exists (it doesn't by default) and `$debian_chroot` doesn't have a value yet.

`${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}` is usually used to define your Bash prompt, for example

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

As the name suggests you can use this variable to indicate which chroot you are in by placing `etc/debian_chroot` into your chroot root folders.

If you don't know what a chroot is chances are you don't need that ;-) But you still may abuse it to include some other information into your Bash prompt

By default it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you never need to use `debian_chroot` then it's a handy place to put the time the command prompt was displayed by using:

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='debian_chroot=$(date +%r)'
```

Type this in your terminal and watch your command prompt change with the time:

```
rick@alien:~$ export PROMPT_COMMAND='debian_chroot=$(date +%r)'

(09:14:59 PM)rick@alien:~$
```

After the time is set once, to get a running clock which updates every second use:

```
while sleep 1;do tput sc;tput cup $(($(tput lines)-1)) 1;printf `date +%r`;tput rc;done &
```

Comment: While this works, it's odd. Why not use a more appropriate variable name in a custom `$PS1`?

Comment: @AdamKatz It doesn't work when a line overflows terminal width and wraps around. Then you can't recall it properly with up arrow. I was actually meaning to fine tune it but ran out of time. I'm not sure what you mean by *"more appropriate variable name"*?

Comment: Safe wrapping requires adding `\[` and `\]` (or `\001` and `\002`) around control characters. The default bash prompt in Debian does this, but your `tput` commands likely break it. This has nothing to do with my comment, in which I propose using a separate variable in the definition of `$PS1` in your `~/.bashrc`

Comment: If you want to add the time to your prompt, consider `export PS1="(\t)$PS1"` with `\t` or `\@` as noted in the `PROMPTING` section of the bash(1) man page. Note, this can't do strftime strings like `%r`, so you could alternatively do `export PS1="($now)$PS1" PROMPT_COMMAND='now=$(date +%r)'` which will preserve the Debian chroot indicator.