# How to automatically set terminal title to directory name without path

Tags: command-line, bash, titlebar

Currently, my bash terminal/tab title is set based on the directory I'm in. For example:

```
bob@bobscomputer:~/i/had/some/great/pie/yesterday
```

This isn't very useful if I have multiple tabs open side-by-side. For example, if I have 4 tabs of the above dir open side-by-side, all I see is

```
bob@bobscomputer:~/i/had...
```

4 times.

I'd like all my terminal titles to be set automatically to just the last part of the path. In the example above, I'd like the title to be

```
yesterday
```

Obviously, the title should change when I change directories. I'd like to do this without changing my prompt, so the prompt and the terminal title should be different.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: For ZSH, look here: https://superuser.com/a/1328085/122021

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Why do you want to do it without modifying your PS1 variable? That is the correct way to do it.

If you run the following, you'll get what you want:

`export PS1="\[\e]0;\W\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ "`

This is just taking the default prompt:

`export PS1="\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ "`

... and replacing `\u@\h: \w` with `\W`.

You can do the same thing with any command that echoes the right escape code:

`echo -en "\e]0;${PWD##*/}\a"`

... but then you'd be constantly fighting bash to stop it from doing it using PS1 (the best way).

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't realized PS1 sets the title and prompt independently. In my .bashrc, under case "$TERM" in xterm*|rxvt*), I set PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\W\a\]$PS1", and it does exactly what I wanted.

Comment: This question does a good job of explaining what all that PS1 gobbledygook means: http://askubuntu.com/questions/404341/where-can-i-find-a-complete-reference-for-the-ps1-variable

Answer (score 4):

Yes. Prepend: `\[\e]0;\W\a\]` to your PS1. This will not change your prompts appearance, but will automatically set your terminal tabs title to the basename of the current working directory.