# Replace $ in terminal prompt with user@host when using SSH

Tags: server, ssh, ps1

I'm using Ubuntu Server over SSH, and I see `$` instead of the name of the user (let's say `test@desktop`, for example).

How can I make the terminal display `test@desktop` instead of `$`?

Comment: This may not be an ideal choice of things to do as the $ shows you to be in standard mode and it will change to # when you are in as root user.  For my system "david@david-Gizmo2 ~ $" standard and "david-Gizmo2 david #" after sudo su (change to Root user).

Comment: You're talking about the PS1 prompt. Refer to [Where can I find a complete reference for the $PS1 variable?](https://askubuntu.com/q/404341)

Comment: @wjandrea I don't understand your guide :/

Comment: @Zanna - voting to close as a duplicate as the problem/solution is the same change and changing PS1 local vs on server is trivial enough that IMO this is a dup.

Comment: Sounds to me like your shell is *not* `/bin/bash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the PS1 variable on the client system and make sure the definition is sourced when you `ssh`.

It's possible that it is already defined in `.bashrc` on the remote system and so you just need to source `.bashrc` by starting an interactive shell (replace `remote-sys` with your remote system's name obviously)

```
ssh remote-sys -t bash -i
```

---

If that doesn't work, because `.bashrc` doesn't exist on the remote system, or doesn't have PS1 defined, and you want to use the same settings on the remote system as your local system, then copy over your own `.bashrc`:

```
scp ~/.bashrc remote-sys:.bashrc
```

Or you can make a file purely to set the prompt the way you want it on the remote system... for example

```
nano .set-prompt
```

enter the text (this sets user@host as the prompt)

```
export PS1="\u@\h "
```

or if you want it to look like the Ubuntu prompt `user@host:working-directory$`

```
export PS1="\u@h:\w$ "
```

or customise however you like. Save the file and exit, then `scp` it to the remote system

```
scp .set-prompt remote-sys:.set-prompt
```

When you `ssh` to the machine you will have to source the file explicitly and tell bash to make the shell interactive:

```
ssh remote-sys -t "bash --rcfile ~/.set-prompt -i"
```

If you do `sudo -i` to change to root on the remote system, the prompt will change again as root's `.bashrc` will be sourced.

Comment: Let me arrive home and I'll try :)

Answer (score 2):

`PS1="/u@/h"` will give you what you are asking for although I don't recommend that you do this as it will make it difficult to ascertain if you are in standard or superuser mode.

To change it back to the default for 16.04 (and earlier?) use `PS1="\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$"`

You can make changes permanent by editing  /etc/bash.bashrc and appending your changes with your favorite editor

Sources:
[this page](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-linux-unix-bash-shell-setup-prompt.html) and testing.

Comment: Elder Geek mirrors much of what I said above.  You certainly want to know at a glance if you are in as standard user or Root and both of our answers explain this. This is why I + marked Elder Geek's answer above.

Comment: That will only change it temporarily.

Comment: you missed a `"` and this sets the prompt to literally `test@desktop` not `user@host` ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you're SSH-ing into a `sh` session, which I think is the case judging by what you have currently, you can add variables and commands to your PS1:

```
PS1='$USER@$(hostname)\$ '
```

If you're SSH-ing into a `bash` session, you have [endless options](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/bash.1.html#contenttoc26), but I'd recommend to use the default if you're just getting into this. To set the PS1 in only the current session, run this:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

To make the change permanent, open the `~/.bashrc` on the remote machine and add the above line to it.

See [Where can I find a complete reference for the $PS1 variable?](https://askubuntu.com/q/404341) to understand what the above line does.

P.S. I don't use SSH very much myself, so you may have to change some other settings to make this stuff work.

Comment: @Zanna Thanks. Could he put it in `~/.profile` instead?

Comment: Yes, that would work :) but remember `.profile` is only sourced if `.bash_profile` and `.bash_login` don't exist... and this is all on the remote system, not local, of course