# Meaning of bash prompts

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh

Trying a VPS (hosting). 
I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 and created a user admin.
Now I'm trying: ssh admin@185.149.129.42
The prompt becomes just a $.

I try:

```
sudo su root
```

The prompt has become

```
root@simple_project:/home/admin#
```

This line is in white letters.

I try:

```
su admin
```

The prompt is in green letters:

```
admin@simple_project:~$
```

Well, in other words three cases:

1. white $;
2. white root;
3. green admin.

I was somehow confused by case 1 for example. And I did:

su root

su admin

And I get my green letters up to the colon:

```
admin@simple_project:~$
```

This looks more familiar than just a bear $.

Could you tell me what these three cases mean? If they really mean anything.

Comment: $ means you have normal user privileges. # means you have root privilege. the third case indicates you are working as another user (admin)

Comment: the prompt ($PS1) is configurable - so you can make it anything you want.  it's also varied by the SHELL you prefer (ie. % can appear instead of $ as default user prompt), which is again configurable (refer .bash_profile, .bashrc etc which can be in $HOME (your home directory) or if none there defaults are used from /etc etc
maybe look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/404341/where-can-i-find-a-complete-reference-for-the-ps1-variable  (I didn't look at much - first that showed up on a search)

Comment: @ravery: Hi there! You have found the comments section, which is an area dedicated to critiquing and requesting clarification. To provide an answer/solution, you should use the "answer" section below (look for the big red "Post Your Answer" button). Hope that helps!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit -- stop already

Comment: @ravery: Wow, no need for the rudeness. Just trying to help you buddy! Have a nice day :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit -- you are providing no help at all. and since this question is closed it can not be answered

Comment: @ravery: I invite you to take The Tour again and learn how this website works. Answers do not go in comments. Teaching you how to use this website (for free!) _is_ helpful. You are welcome.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit -- stop

Comment: @ravery: Rude again. Take a chill pill, pal! Smile and be nice to others. Take care.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit -- not rude at all. I don't need you to post the same comment to every post I have made.

Comment: @ravery: Good thing I didn't then! And hopefully now you have learnt how to use this website it won't be necessary in the future, either. Cheers! (Yes, very rude.)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - yoou would have if I didn't stop you. already 5 had been made

Comment: @ravery: That is simply false. You have not "stopped" anything. You have only been rude in the face of somebody trying to help you to become a more productive user. I shall now be ignoring you and your rudeness henceforth.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit -- I have not been rude. the rudeness is you repeatedly making the same post. not more to be said