# Setting a more interactive shell prompt

Tags: bash, software-recommendation, ps1

I went through the website for Tilix and came across a very beautiful shell prompt in one of the images on the website. I want to know if that is just for show(a gimmick) or is it actually possible to have such a prompt...

[image]

This question is not similar to other question as it does not mention any software in it. It is not a normal prompt configuration. It is at best an attempt to get software recommendation.

[How can I install and use powerline plugin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/283908/how-can-i-install-and-use-powerline-plugin) or [Where can I find a complete reference for the $PS1 variable?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404341/where-can-i-find-a-complete-reference-for-the-ps1-variable) do not cover the scope of this question as I did not know that a software such as `powerline` existed but did know that simple modifications to PS1 does not give the output desired in other words understanding PS1 references does not solve the problem mentioned above

Comment: of course it's possible! you mean the terminal path and presentation with versioning contextual highlighting? yeah it's possible it's powerline : https://askubuntu.com/questions/283908/how-can-i-install-and-use-powerline-plugin

Comment: @tatsu, can you please add this to an answer so that I can mark that this question has an answer

Comment: no @tatsu mark it as a duplicate ;-)

Comment: We'll it's not a duplicate @Rinzwind. My question is for a possibility of a software to exist. The linked one is asking about the package that the OP knows exists

Comment: That software is called terminal but fine I can find another one if you want ;-) https://askubuntu.com/questions/283908/how-can-i-install-and-use-powerline-plugin  heck has the exact same example :P

Comment: True but does the OP for that question not know which plugin to use. How am I supposed to know from a website image what to use. Am I supposed to use google reverse image search for that. What is the use of community if it can't help me find some code that can solve a problem

Comment: Your link to the question helped but tell me how is that question an exact replacement for a question where no name is mentioned just a graphic which could for all my knowleged have been the work of a graphic designer(just a concept)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for here is [powerline](https://github.com/b-ryan/powerline-shell).

You can install it by following these steps :

```
sudo apt install powerline
```

then

```
gedit ~/.bashrc
```

and add the following to the end :

```
if [ -f `which powerline-daemon` ]; then
  powerline-daemon -q
  POWERLINE_BASH_CONTINUATION=1
  POWERLINE_BASH_SELECT=1
  . /usr/share/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
fi
```

now close and reopen your terminal.