# How to return to normal root user

Tags: command-line

can someone assist, i would like to return to my normal terminal that has $ root symbol. Right now am in terminal with # root symbol saying bash, how do i get back to the $ root

Comment: Press the two buttons CTRL+D.

Comment: Or you can type exit

Comment: both CTRL + D and exit is not working, can you assist me to get out of bash

Comment: I think you may be misusing the term "root." There is a typical user prompt (`$`), and there is a typical root prompt (`#`). Both can be customized to something else. So your phrase "*normal terminal that has `$` root symbol*" could be interpreted two different ways.

Answer (score 1):

The symbol that you see doesn't really matter too much, other than a customisable indication of which user is logged in. The command prompt that you see is highly customisable using the [`PS1` environmental variable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404341/where-can-i-find-a-complete-reference-for-the-ps1-variable).

If you want to know which user you are currently logged in as, the command you need is: `whoami`

If you want to switch to another user, try:

`su <username>`

or `ctrl-D` to exit the current shell and return to your previous shell.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seem to be about the special variable `\$` that are available in the Bash prompt, which is also [explained here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404341/where-can-i-find-a-complete-reference-for-the-ps1-variable).

The variable `\$` in the PS1 prompt is really simple:

- `\$` expands to `#` for `root` (UID = 0) and `$` for all other users.

In relation to your question, this means that if the prompt shows `#`, then you ARE logged in as `root`. If you then type `exit` and <kbd>Enter</kbd> and the prompt now shows `$`, this means you ARE NOT logged in as `root`.

The variable `\$` is simply a quick way to indicate whether you're logged in as `root` (UID = 0) or not.