# Ubuntu on Chromebook: (precise) "myusername"@localhost: what is precise?

Tags: 12.04, chromebook

I am new to Ubuntu, so this might be a silly question.
I just followed the instruction online and installed Ubuntu on my Acer CB3-111 Chromebook.
I noticed something different than the Ubuntu that I installed on my windows PC.
The command line is like this:

```
(precise)myusername@localhost:~$
```

What does the `(precise)` mean? I didn't have this on the other laptop. My professor's Ubuntu doesn't show this either. Did I install a wrong version of Ubuntu? I am using Ubuntu for bioinformatics mainly. How do I get rid of the word `precise`?

And what is `localhost`? I used to have something like this:

```
myusername@myusername:~$
```

Can I change this also?

Answer (score 2):

The `(precise)` indicates that you're running inside a `chroot`, not inside a normal Ubuntu installation. (Are you using Crouton?) To remove it, edit `~/.bashrc`, find the following lines:

```bsh
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

Comment them out by adding a `#` at the beginning of each line.

The `localhost` part is the hostname of your chroot. On your dual-boot system (the one with Windows), your hostname and username happened to be the same. To set the hostname, use `hostnamectl`:

```
hostnamectl set-hostname myusername
```

- [What does "${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}" do in my terminal prompt?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372849/what-does-debian-chrootdebian-chroot-do-in-my-terminal-prompt)
- [How do I change the hostname without a restart?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87665/how-do-i-change-the-hostname-without-a-restart/516898#516898)