# bash: ${debian_chroot!-}: bad substitution

Tags: bash, scripts, bashrc, error-handling, chroot

So I'm learning how to shell script and i got this error. Every thing I've read on the other posts makes it seem like a directory file path like most terminal commands have stashed away. My version of ubuntu trusty has nada zip anything closed to being named this. So now I'm thinking that debian_chroot is a class / function for double checking the shell and I'm wondering exactly how I should edit the .bashrc to include my source files to fix shut this up. What exactly does this do for chroot and with the root / kernel. I think it just checks so user writes will function properly but I'm not sure.

```
       sooloo@Trusty:~$ grep 'debian_chroot' ~/.bashrc
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
sooloo@Trusty:~$ 



    sooloo@Trusty:~$ grep 'debian_chroot' ~/.bashrc -vv -xml
grep: invalid max count
sooloo@Trusty:~$ grep 'debian_chroot' ~/.bashrc -vvnn
1:# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
2:# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
3:# for examples
4:
5:# If not running interactively, don't do anything
6:case $- in
7:    *i*) ;;
8:      *) return;;
9:esac
10:
11:# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
12:# See bash(1) for more options
13:HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth
14:
15:# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
16:shopt -s histappend
17:
18:# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
19:HISTSIZE=1000
20:HISTFILESIZE=2000
21:
22:# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
23:# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
24:shopt -s checkwinsize
25:
26:# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
27:# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
28:#shopt -s globstar
29:
30:# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
31:[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"
32:
33:# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
36:fi
37:
38:# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
39:case "$TERM" in
40:    xterm-color) color_prompt=yes;;
41:esac
42:
43:# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
44:# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
45:# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
46:#force_color_prompt=yes
47:
48:if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
49:    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
50: # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
51: # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
52: # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
53: color_prompt=yes
54:    else
55: color_prompt=
56:    fi
57:fi
58:
59:if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
61:else
63:fi
64:unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
65:
66:# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
67:case "$TERM" in
68:xterm*|rxvt*)
70:    ;;
71:*)
72:    ;;
73:esac
74:
75:# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
76:if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
77:    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
78:    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
79:    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
80:    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'
81:
82:    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
83:    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
84:    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
85:fi
86:
87:# some more ls aliases
88:alias ll='ls -alF'
89:alias la='ls -A'
90:alias l='ls -CF'
91:
92:# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
93:#   sleep 10; alert
94:alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'
95:
96:# Alias definitions.
97:# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
98:# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
99:# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.
100:
101:if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
102:    . ~/.bash_aliases
103:fi
104:
105:# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
106:# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
107:# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
108:if ! shopt -oq posix; then
109:  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
110:    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
111:  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
112:    . /etc/bash_completion
113:  fi
114:fi
sooloo@Trusty:~$
```

Comment: It should be related to `PS1` environment variable..whats the output of `grep 'debian_chroot' ~/.bashrc` ?

Comment: this will help http://askubuntu.com/questions/372849/what-does-debian-chrootdebian-chroot-do-in-my-terminal-prompt ;)

Comment: When are you getting this error ? while doing what i mean ?

Comment: It shows any time I open my terminal. I was configuring a ascii image to show in my shell. Any time I make the ascii art show on program load as the .bashrc it tells me this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since posting this I have learned that the error was due to a bug in the .bashrc folder when evoking my script while summoning the terminal. I had a duplicate command in my source file that was all so in the .bashrc file to evoke my script. This is why it worked but it looked back at itself as an error since it was essentially opening twice inside itself to alter the shell in a way. So it was still the shell and my script was active but it was called again and it no longer recognized the type of shell running and gave me the error.

Comment: Why is this in a quote block?