# Is .bashrc correctly setting the graphical terminal title?

Tags: bash, bashrc, ps1

From the default `.bashrc` is this:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac
```

The result is examined by issuing the echo command:

```
$ echo $PS1
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$
```

It appears that the `${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}` conditional insertion will be performed for the command line prompt but not for the terminal title. It appears the `.bashrc` author intended it to be displayed in both places just to the left of `user@host` but in fact it did not make it into both places. The evaluation of `debian_chroot` happened in defining PS1 but it was not meant to be evaluated at that time, rather it was meant to be evaluated at the time of prompting. The root of the problem is that when building strings `""` quoting evaluates and `''` quoting does not. The evaluation was early because the whole thing enclosed in `\[` `\]` was meant for the title. Is interpretation correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say the whole thing is irrelevant. [`debian_chroot` is set in `/etc/bash.bashrc`](https://askubuntu.com/a/372862/158442). It is a fair bet that, in the normal course of things, if the variable was set, a new shell has been started - why would `/etc/bash.bashrc` be sourced otherwise? And in that case, `~/.bashrc` would be sourced as well. So, either the variable is set when `PS1` is set and modified in the lines you show, or it isn't, and it won't be. The effect is the same.

I can only guess at why the original developer used single quotes while setting `PS1` in the first place. Presumably, the dev has learned caution and uses `""` only when necessary, which it is when modifying `PS1`.

Note that `:+` just means do nothing if the variable is unset.

Comment: How does PS1 manage to put $debian_chroot into the terminal title?

Comment: @H2ONaCl if `debian_chroot` was set, its value would be in the title-setting part.

Comment: But then would you not expect PS1 to contain two instances of ${var:+var}. Once for the prompt and once for the title. My PS1 has only one instance.

Comment: @H2ONaCl have you read my answer at all? Either the variable is set when PS1 is being set, or it isn't. The instance that you speak of meaningless, since the variable is unset. If it were set, you'd have the content in the title-setting part, and the instance you see now would still be there, and this time it would evaluate to something. Do us all favour and test it: `debian_chroot=foo bash`.

Comment: So you think ${var:+var} should be available for evaluation for the purpose of the title when .bashrc is invoked, but not available later for the evaluation of PS1. And for the prompt ${var:+var} should not be evaluated when .bashrc is invoked, but available to be evaluated in PS1 later? I don't understand the inconsistency.

Comment: @H2ONaCl What? When did I say anything like that?

Comment: I mean do you think the .bashrc is okay with respect to setting PS1 such that the title part at the time of displaying the title will not evaluate ${var:+var} given the var was undefined for me when .bashrc was invoked but the prompt part can evaluate ${var:+var} at the time of displaying the prompt because it was included in PS1 as a literal.

Comment: @H2ONaCl Again, have you read my answer at all? Go back, read it again, and tell me when `debian_chroot` is set.

Answer (score 1):

`${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}` insertion depends on the presence of `$debian_chroot` variable or `/etc/debian_chroot` file.

Here's a simple example. In the screenshot bellow I'm connected through ssh to my Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu Snappy on it, which has `$debian_chroot` variable set ( by default ), while my laptop's Ubuntu does not. You can see the resulting prompt in the tabs, and in both cases variable for `$TERM` is `xterm`

[image]

Now if the variable `$TERM` was something else, it wouldn't alter the GUI terminal title. That could be connecting to a `screen` session, for example, where variable `$TERM` is `screen`.

Comment: But your terminal title is already not the default. Your title is not user@host:directory, although your tabs are.

Comment: @H2ONaCl Original xterm didn't have tabs , so the title of the xterm window would be user@host:directory.  Now we have terminal emulators with tabs and it's up to individual program to set that behavior. I'm using sakura which gives this behavior. `gnome-terminal` changes window title to whatever current tab title is.  I'm sure other terminals behave differently too

Comment: If I'm wrong then why does my PS1 have only one conditional insertion?

Comment: @H2ONaCl you mean only one conditional insertion with the `case "$TERM" in` part ?

Comment: @H2ONaCl do you know how to access chat ? Let's go there

Comment: There is only one ${var:+var} in the PS1 definition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33605/discussion-between-h2onacl-and-serg).