# How can I use the arrow sign in my bash prompt?

Tags: bash, bashrc, prompt

How can I use these red and green arrow signs in the bash prompt?

[image]

## update 1

This is my `.bashrc`  file

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\[\033[00m\]\ 
[\033[01;34m\]→  \w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}→  \w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt
```

I want this arrow to be colored as @dessert answered before
(turn red and green for false and true command )

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `bash`’s `PROMPT_COMMAND` to run a function which builds your prompt, e.g.:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND=build_prompt

build_prompt() {
  EXIT=$?               # save exit code of last command
  red='\[\e[0;31m\]'    # colors
  green='\[\e[0;32m\]'
  cyan='\[\e[1;36m\]'
  reset='\[\e[0m\]'
  PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}'  # begin prompt

  if [ $EXIT != 0 ]; then  # add arrow color dependent on exit code
    PS1+="$red"
  else
    PS1+="$green"
  fi

  PS1+="→$reset  $cyan\w$reset \\$ " # construct rest of prompt
}
```

Add this code to your `~/.bashrc` file and open a new terminal or run `. ~/.bashrc` in an existing one for the changes to take effect. Note that I added the usual `\$` at the end, this prints `$` normally and `#` if you’re root, thus preventing you from running commands as root unwittingly. The `false` command is a good way to test the non-zero exit code variant:

[image: result]

If you’re into prompt themeing you should definitely take a look at the `zsh` shell (package `zsh`), whose famous configuration framework [Oh My Zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) alone comes with [over hundred themes](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/Themes). Additionally there are many other plugins available, for example [the ￼Spaceship ZSH prompt](https://github.com/denysdovhan/spaceship-prompt).

#### Links

- [How can I shorten my command line (bash) prompt?](https://askubuntu.com/q/145618/507051)
- [Bash Prompt with Last Exit Code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16715103/6164712)
- [Easy Bash PS1 Generator](http://ezprompt.net)
- [Bash tips: Colors and formatting](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting)
- [What color codes can I use in my PS1 prompt?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124407/246819)
- [What does "${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}" do in my terminal prompt?](https://askubuntu.com/q/372849/507051)

Comment: While this is a **great plain-bash solution**, you could take a look at zsh (as a replacement of bash) and especially the [Spaceship prompt](https://github.com/denysdovhan/spaceship-prompt)

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants that a virtualenv prompt shows up before the arrows do:

```
build_prompt() {
    EXIT=$?               
    red='\[\e[1;31m\]'
    green='\[\e[1;32m\]'
    blue='\[\e[1;34m\]'
    cyan='\[\e[1;36m\]'
    reset='\[\e[0m\]'

    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}'

    if [ -z "$VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT" ] ; then
        _OLD_VIRTUAL_PS1="$PS1"
        if [ "`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`" = "__" ] ; then
            PS1="[`basename \`dirname \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"\``] $PS1"
        elif [ "$VIRTUAL_ENV" != "" ]; then
            PS1="(`basename \"$VIRTUAL_ENV\"`)$PS1"
        fi
        if [ $EXIT != 0 ]; then
            PS1+="$red"
        else
            PS1+="$green"
        fi
    fi
    PS1+="→$reset  $cyan\w$reset \\$ "
    export PS1
}

PROMPT_COMMAND=build_prompt
```

This is a mix o this current post and this: [Why is virtualenv not setting my terminal prompt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14987013/why-is-virtualenv-not-setting-my-terminal-prompt)